# Cyrrilic letters changin to ?? in wordpress editor

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm working a wordpress site which is copied to multiple installations with WP-All-in-one-migration plugin.

The cyrrilic letters work fine in the home server, but in the clients server they turn to ?? in the wordpress editor after update.

The font is added through Google Fonts as follows:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
```

The clients server also has a https sertificate, could this be involved?

[image: before update]
[image: after update]

Comment: Make sure the clients database uses the same encoding as your home server does.

Comment: Most probably encoding and character set. Czech language works fine